# C String Parsing and conversion

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf, c-strings

I have a String formatted like this:
`"1,1100,1,1200"`
I want to break this out into 2 variables (int preferably)
to: 

`int data_1 = 1100
int data_2 = 1200`

Where the values are set from parsing the input string.

Comment: How do you get `1100` out of `"1,1150,1,1200"`?

Comment: [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

Comment: What have you tried? What part are you having problems with?

Comment: Yeah its meant to be 1100 not 1150. Its a variable in that range. Which is why I made the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
int data_1 = 1150
```

instead of

```
int data_1 = 1100
```

Though having 1150 you can always get 1100.:)

Try something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "1,1150,1,1200";
    int x, y;

    sscanf( s, "%*d , %d , %*d , %d ", &x, &y );

    printf( "x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 1150, y = 1200
```

Another approach provided that the string is contained in a character array can look like this

```
char s[] = "1,1150,1,1200";
```

is to use functions `strtok` and `atoi`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "1,1150,1,1200";
    int data[2] = { 0 };
    const char *delim = ", ";

    char *p = strtok( s, delim );

    for ( size_t i = 0; p != NULL; p = strtok( NULL, delim ) )
    {
        int value = atoi( p );

        if ( i % 2 != 0 ) data[i / 2] = value;

        ++i;
    }

    printf( "data[0] = %d, data[1] = %d\n", data[0], data[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
data[0] = 1150, data[1] = 1200
```

And at last you can extract substrings using functions `strcspn` and `strspn` copy them into a separate array and apply the function `atoi`.